# Solving an equation: Reduce command produces failure message

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following equation for c:

[image: Equation to be solved]

All variables can only take positive values and c>s. I have tried the following code:

```
Reduce[(r (c d+g  t))/(t (d r+b t)) (c-s) Log[(c d r+g r t)/(c d r+b c t)]-l (g r-b c)/(d r+b t)==0&&r>0&&d>0&&g>0&&t>0&&b>0&&c>s>0&&l>0,c,Reals]
```

After running for a while, Mathematica returns

Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Can anyone give me a hint of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to imagine that this complicated equation can be analytically solved. However, the solution should be possible for `l==0`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @yarchik. You are right, for  l==0 it is easily solved. Unfortunately, this is excluded by context. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: A firm "No, that is impossible in full generality!" However, you may still try to reduce the number of parameters and seek a series solution in a well-defined interval. But before that you can use numerical methods to better understand the behavior of roots of this equation, in particular, existence and uniqueness.